# PHP code analyzer to determine classes/extensions used

Tags: php, code-analysis, lexical-analysis

#### Problem

I have a legacy codebase I need to analyze and determine *dependencies*. Particularly the dependencies on classes (internal/external) and extensions (Memcache, PDO, etc).

#### What I've Tried

I have reviewed the tools listed in [*Is there a static code analyzer for PHP files?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files). Unfortunately, this post is dated and most of the promising tools like [phpCallGraph](http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net) no longer work.

My thought was to analyze the code lexically and look for *class* tokens. Reviewing a list of these would at least allow me to visually determine *dependencies*. However finding *OtherClass* in the following code may be complex:

```
$classname = 'OtherClass';
echo $classname::doubleColon();
```

In the end, I doubt I'm the first to need this. I'm sure a tool or combination of tools exist to provide what I need. So I'm asking the SO community before writing this myself.

#### Update

Ideally this *tool* will analyze multiple files with complete code coverage. As such, tools like Xdebug, while great, are not solutions to this exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of phpCallGraph you could use Gopal Vijayaraghavan's [inclued extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/inclued) which in combination with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) gives you a nice looking graph of all included files for a certain execution path.

Example:

[image]

Moreover, I'd recommend [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) (a PHP debugger) which offers a profiler that outputs data consumable by [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html). Use the debugger with a compatible IDE to follow the execution path (which helped me a lot to wade thru e.g. Drupal's massive call-stack).

Combine both and you should get a fairly thourough overview.

**EDIT**

Searched the web and found [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php) - an eclipse plugin that looks like it could be the right tool for you (30 day free trial which should be enough to give you a head start).

Comment: I'll look at inclued. As far as Xdebug, it's my understanding it requires *active* code execution. Furthermore, it would only profile the *sample* code path. Both of which hinder the audit of complete code coverage.

Comment: Seems as inclued works similarly to Xdebug and therefore doesn't fit my exact need. Good tools though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think PhpCodeAnalyzer is exactly what you're looking for - https://github.com/wapmorgan/PhpCodeAnalyzer
It print list of all used external extensions in code base.