# Regular expression to find accidental assignments in a conditional statement

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I've gotten bitten more than once by a bug where you accidentally assign a variable inside a conditional statement, like `if`.

I'm looking to grep my sources for such occurances. I created an expression that works in PHP for the simple case, but was wondering if anyone could optimize it or handle the more interesting cases.

Samples:

```
if ($var = 3)       //MATCH
if($var = 3)        //MATCH
if($var=3)          //MATCH
if ( $var = 3)      //MATCH
if ($var == $var2)  
if ($var = $var3)   //MATCH
if ( $var === 7)
if( $var == 8 || $var = 9) //MATCH
if (($var == 7 ) && ($var ==10))
```

The simple cases are handled well by `if\s*\([\$a-zA-Z\d\s]*=[\$a-zA-Z\d\s]*\)` but it would be nice to come up with something that works for the extended versions at the bottom of the sample.

Any ideas on better expressions?

Comment: I'm trying to match an `if`

Comment: @sputnick regex has an if: `(?(ifregex)thenregex|elseregex)`

Comment: you'll also want to catch any other conditionals, which are all potential assignments. There's probably no way to catch everything unless you were parsing tokenized.

Comment: You could just check if the whole line contains both `if` and `==` - assuming the blocks are line-wrapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's assume you don't have cases like this (C example):

```
if ((a = b) == c)
```

because understanding these cases needs an actual parser.

Now, simply put, you want to match `=` but not `==\+`. Therefore:

```
if\([^=]\|==\+\)*[^=]=[^=]\([^=]\|==\+\)*$
```

What it says:

- `if`: match the first if.
- `[^=]`: any character but `=`
- `==\+`: `==` and `===`
- `\([^=]\|==\+\)*`: anything that is not `=` or is `==` or `===`. This includes all the whitespace, the beginning `(`, ending `)` etc. This comes both before and after the isolated `=`.
- `[^=]=[^=]`: isolated `=`.

Comment: Awesome. I tried it on my project and it didnt find anything. So I guess that means I wrote good code this time. Ha! Cheers!

Comment: @akatakritos, I'm not a php developer, but I would have expected whatever compiler/interpreter reads that code should give you warnings, doesn't it?

Comment: Accidental assignment, AFAIK is not any sort of warning in PHP. I miss C# where its a compile error. :(

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are not the best tool to parse code.

For most languages there are linting tools that check your code. I have no experience with PHP but you'll find plenty of pointers here: [Is there a static code analyzer [like Lint] for PHP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

Comment: Hey thanks for that link, i'll look at some of those tools. I was looking for something quick and dirty, but once one of those tools is up and running, it should give more accurate results.